# Connected prepositional phrases

Tags: prepositional-phrases, ellipsis, coordination

It is possible, as we all know, to say those sentences below.

> It was given to me by a kind woman.
>
> I walked on the top of the building with my friend under a moon light.

One common point between those sentences is that the prepositional phrases are not connected by a conjunction.

It feels and sounds natural to me to hear and write those sentences, but when I apply my logic to it, it always feels that there should be a conjunction between those prepositional phrases as below.

> It was given to me (and) by a kind woman. = It was given to me and
>   given by a kind woman.
>
> I walked on the top of the building (and) with my friend (and) under a
>   moon light. = I walked on the top of the building and walked with my
>   friend and walked under a moon light.

It seems that all those connected prepositional phrases are the product of coordinate ellipsis: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordination_(linguistics)

So why isn't the conjunction used? Is certain grammar rule applied to it?

Comment: I think the onus is on you to explain why a conjunction is needed. You appeal to your logic, but your logic is not directly accessible to us, at least not to me: you’d need to explain it better. I would use a conjunction only to emphasise something surprising: “It was given to me, and by that stingy woman (no less).”

Comment: I thought I explained it quite expressively. Also, another point I will make here: I agree that "and" sounds superfluous when used in the sentence I provided above -- but my logic can stretch out only so far, which leaves me no choice but to ask this question to someone.

Comment: I've been thinking about your question. And if it is about logic, then I think _it was given to me and was given by a kind woman_ does not imply that the woman gave it to me. Other possibilities are: after it was given to me by someone else, I sold it to the kind woman, and then she gave it to X; or she gave it to Y, and Y gave it to me. You see, the original sentence, with no "ands", does not suffer from those ambiguities.

Answer (score 1):

- (original) It was given to me by a kind woman. (passive voice—using "by" *makes it passive*.)
- A kind woman gave it to me. (same thought, but transformed to *active voice*)

The active voice phrasing has only one prepositional phrase ("to me".) The preposition "to" indicates  the *indirect object* "me"; the *direct object* "it"needs no preposition.

I hope you can see that there is no logical need for (nor even a possibility of) a conjunction in the *active voice* construction, so there is likewise no logical need for a conjunction in the original construction.

Your example of the moonlight walk on top of the building uses a longer series of prepositional phrases.

Let's take a different example to see how this works:

- the keyhole *of the lock* **in the door** *by the gate* **of the city**...

The prepositional phrases attach consecutively, each preposition applying at its own level to link one noun logically to the next.

One can continue this indefinitely.

The A [of the B [in the C [by the D [of the E]]]]...

There is no need for a conjunction, because each noun has *only one relation to the next one*, which is fully specified by that preposition.

You might think of this as a *stack*, or a *nest*. The reader parses the multiple prepositional phrases by "unstacking" or "unwrapping" as indicated by the brackets, like  evaluating a mathematical expression with parentheses. The nesting itself defines the relationships of the elements. Thus:

- the keyhole is **of** the lock, which is **in** the door, which is **by** the gate, which is **of** the city.

That's it. As we say...  "No Ifs, Ands or buts about it!" http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/no+ifs+ands+or+buts+about+it

Or more accurately:
*No Ands or Ors.*
No conjunction needed. None possible. None "elided".

+++++++++
oh, by the way, it's more idiomatic to say "under **the** moonlight" or "**by** the light **of** the moon"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to link a simple noun or a noun phrase to a clause, you use a preposition. If you want to link a clause (something that contains a verb) you use a conjunction. Look that the second parts of the two sentences:

> a kind woman.
>
> my friend under a moon light

They do not contain a verb, so you use a preposition, not a conjunction.

Note that English can be confusing because many words can be both a preposition and a conjunction:

> Wash your hands before dinner (preposition + noun)
>
> Wash your hands before you eat (conjunction + clause)